# ReCaptcha: cant get it to work in a exisiting modal dialog consuming web service

Tags: ajax, json, web-services, webforms, recaptcha

Community -

I'm stuck for couple days on this and decide to go with a iFrame solution and a regular embedded page with a basic reCaptcha plugin using a Page.IsValid {} on the server functionality.

Basiccaly I have an older WebForm ASP.NET 2.0 clients website with a Modal Dialog implemented using a Ajax/JSON call to a MailSend WebService and now integrating a clients wish having a reCaptcha functionality within the modal dialog gets a pain.

After several trials with some basic code and all over not completed code pieces on several blogs around the net I do give up - I go to create a separate page with a regular send to friend mail form and will call it from the parent page with jQuery in a iFrame.

Did anyone had some more luck consuming a reCaptcha Validate Web Service within a modal dialog without a Postback or without using the iFrame way?

I'm thankful for any idea.

Martin

Answer (score 0):

Allright. Me and my co-worker gave up on validate re-captcha thru web service. We finished the task with a iFrame and a jQuery FancyBox modal dialog solution. It solved our problem and it looks good. But I will come back to do the research and try the first way to solve as well at a later point.